# Hover image link, change text css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a wordpress plugin, so I don't want to edit the HTML output too much.  Is there anything I can do here so hovering the image OR the text will give the same result which is just changing the text to a different color.

Here is what im working with - http://jsfiddle.net/3JE62/

```
<section id="featured-post-5" class="widget featuredpost">
<div class="post-240 post type-post status-publish format-standard category-projects entry gfwa-3 gfwa-odd"><a href="http://www.kylezipp.com/really-awesome-people/" title="Really Awesome People" class="alignnone"><img width="250" height="200" src="http://www.kylezipp.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/rap.png" class="alignnone" alt="rap"></a>
<h2><a href="http://www.kylezipp.com/really-awesome-people/" title="Really Awesome People">Really Awesome People</a></h2></div><!--end post_class()--></div>
</section>
```

Comment: code code code code code code code

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: Sorry about that, just hit save too soon.

Comment: This output is with Genesis Featured Post Amplified.  I get similar output when just using the default Genesis Featured Post widget, so either would work but this has a few hooks available for future updates if needed.

Comment: OT: I think you have an extra `</div>` before the `</section>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your selector to get that `<a>` :

```
#featured-post-5 a:hover, #featured-post-5 a:hover + h2 a {
color: #5fb336;
}
```

the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/3JE62/2/**

Comment: Thanks for this.  I guess I never learned this + in CSS, but it is perfect.